# Entity framework and migration with datetime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, migration

I am using EF 4.3 and the migration script the come along.
But I have an issue with a property that does not get his field created.

```
public class Test {
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime UpdateUtc { get; set; }

}
```

When I run the command `Add-Migration` here is the code that is generate:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "Test",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Author = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }
```

My first thought was because of the `ScaffoldColumn` attribute but the Author field is correctly add. The only difference I see is that the type of the field `UpdateUtc`  is not a primitive type.

What would cause this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it by hand, using something like:

```
UpdateUtc = c.DateTime()
```

I think it should be it. Then update the database using Update command. 
When you generate the database, please look at the name of the column generated and see if it is something like [UpdateUtc]. If so, then the name UpdateUtc si reserved and cannot be used.

Comment: I had eventually made the change you've suggest, but I was just wondering why Add-Migration was not able to add it by himself. To answer your question the column name is not a reserved keyword as it appear properly in the DB.